# Discretizing variable and providing limits

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

The base `cut` function and the `dplyr` `cut_*` functions both discretize continuous variables. But none of these offer the ability to specify upper/lower bounds to include in the discretized intervals.

For example, using `cut_number` in the below example

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(901)
df = tibble(x =runif(min = 0.1, max = 0.9, n = 5)) %>% 
    arrange(x)

df = df %>% 
    mutate(x_binned = cut_number(x, n=3))

df
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>       x x_binned     
#>   <dbl> <fct>        
#> 1 0.187 [0.187,0.529]
#> 2 0.524 [0.187,0.529]
#> 3 0.540 (0.529,0.671]
#> 4 0.737 (0.671,0.768]
#> 5 0.768 (0.671,0.768]
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The bottom interval is `[0.187, 0.529]` and the top interval is `[0.671, 0.768]`. But I need the intervals to include 0 and 1, or be `[0, 0.529]` and `[0.671, 1.0]`.  Is there an easy way to specify these bounds when discretizing continuous variables?

Comment: Given that the lower limit of your `runif` distribution is 0.1, what does it mean to include a lower bound (0) below the possible range of sampled values?

Comment: You could use `case_when` or its base equivalent, `switch`, to build a function that supports defining double-ended closed intervals on vectors. (I try to avoid nested or cascaded `ifelse` solutions when possible.)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sequence by specifying it's length and use it in `cut` as `breaks`.

```
n <- 3
seq(0, 1, length.out = n)
#[1] 0.0 0.5 1.0

transform(df, x_binned = cut(x, seq(0, 1, length.out = n)))

#      x x_binned
#1 0.187  (0,0.5]
#2 0.524  (0.5,1]
#3 0.540  (0.5,1]
#4 0.737  (0.5,1]
#5 0.768  (0.5,1]
```